# General Relativity and cosmology

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, differentiation

What is the physical meaning of Ricci scalar is a covariantly constant?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? To my mind, the Ricci scalar itself is a physical quantity and the physical meaning of it being (covariantly) constant is thus self-evident, i.e., it has the same value at all spacetime points.

Comment: I guess he mean $\nabla_{\mu} \, R = 0$, which is true for the spatial section in an homogeneous spacetime.  However, $R$ isn't a constant in the full spacetime.  $R^{(3)} = \text{cste}$ is an expression of the homogeneity of the space section.